# gcc: gnustep-config: No such file or directory and unrecognized command line option -fobjc-flags

Tags: objective-c, gcc, gnustep

Hi all please provide me solution for this i want to execute objective using command line

1)
**command :** gcc -o filename `'gnustep-config --objc-flags'` `'gnustep-config --base-libs'` -o filename.m

**error :** 
gcc: `gnustep-config: No such file or directory
gcc:`gnustep-config: No such file or directory
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fobjc-flags`"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fbase-libs`"

2)
**command  :** gcc -o filename  `'gnustep-config --objc-flags'` -lgnustep-base filename.m

**error :**
gcc: `gnustep-config: No such file or directory
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fobjc-flags`"

When i used "-lgnustep-base" one of my error resolved but what about  gnustep-config --objc-flags package...

Please provide me solution ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I found the solution !!!!

just type the command "gnustep-config --objc-flags"  in command prompt...

You will get o/p like : " /-MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I. -I/root/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep "

so now you need to copy all this and placed it to the command prompt like this:

"gcc -MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I. -I/root/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep -o filename -lgnustep-base  filename.m "

type all command without any space.......